# Visual Basic 2010 Express for Phone: Data at the root level is invalid (XML)

Tags: xml, vb.net, windows-phone-7, xml-parsing

First I will link the start of my rather large xml document and then the code I am using to read the xml document; which compiles bu the following exception is thrown. "Data at the root level is invalid. Line 1, position 1"

```
<icalendar xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:icalendar-2.0">
<!--
 created utilizing kigkonsult.se iCalcreator 2.16.12 iCal2XMl (rfc6321) 
-->
<vcalendar>
<properties>
<prodid>
<text>
-//opendata.unm.edu//NONSGML kigkonsult.se iCalcreator 2.16.12//
</text>
</prodid>
<version>
<text>2.0</text>
</version>
<method>
<text>PUBLISH</text>
</method>
</properties>
<components>
<vevent>
<properties>
<uid>
<text>caf72d80-edec-4175-96d8-802a68fa186f</text>
</uid>
<dtstamp>
<date-time>2013-10-17T20:45:00Z</date-time>
</dtstamp>
<summary>
<text>UFO Speaker Stanton Friedman</text>
</summary>
<description>
```

My Visual Basic 2010 Express for Phone Code:

```
Public Sub LoadData()
        Try
            Dim filePathUnm As String = "http://datastore.unm.edu/events/events.xml"

            Dim rs As XmlReaderSettings = New XmlReaderSettings()
            rs.DtdProcessing = DtdProcessing.Parse
            rs.IgnoreWhitespace = True
            Dim unmEventXml As XmlReader = XmlReader.Create(New StringReader(filePathUnm), rs)

            While unmEventXml.Read()
                Select Case unmEventXml.NodeType

                End Select

            End While
            Me.IsDataLoaded = True
        Catch ex As XmlException
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
        End Try
    End Sub
```

Thank you very much! This xml code is from a public repository and so I need to be able to read it. Also this is at the top of the repository. "This XML file does not appear to have any style information associated with it. The document tree is shown below." Here is the link to the repository: http://datastore.unm.edu/events/events.xml

Comment: Much like your [other question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19458514/operation-not-permitted-on-isolatedstoragefilestream-visual-studio-2010-express), the XmlReader is for local files only. If you need to get the content from web, use HttpClient, WebClient or HttpWebRequest