# Operation not permitted on IsolatedStorageFileStream: Visual Studio 2010 Express for Phone

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, windows-phone-7, isolatedstorage

I am having this error: "Operation not permitted on IsolatedStorageFileStream." I am using visual studio 2010 express for phone c#.

Here is my code:

```
        public void LoadData()
        {
           string xmlUrl = "http://datastore.unm.edu/events/events.xml";

        using (IsolatedStorageFile storage = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
        {

            using (var isoFileStream = new IsolatedStorageFileStream(xmlUrl, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.ReadWrite, FileShare.Read, storage))
            {
                using (XmlReader xreader = XmlReader.Create(isoFileStream))
                {

                }

            }

        }
        }
```

Thank you for your help! It's much appreciated.

Comment: IsolatedStorage is for local files, not for remote (web based) files. Are you trying to read the xml from the web?

Comment: Thank you for responding, yes I am trying to read the file from the web.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want to read a xml from the web  you should use  the WebClient class. WebClient provides common methods for sending data to and receiving data from a resource identified by a URI.

Here's a little example

```
   private WebClient webClient;

    public Example()
    {
        webClient.DownloadStringCompleted += new DownloadStringCompletedEventHandler(DownloadStringCompleted);
        webClient.DownloadStringAsync(new Uri("http://datastore.unm.edu/events/events.xml", UriKind.Absolute));
    }

    private void DownloadStringCompleted(object sender, DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs e)
    {

        XElement Xmlparse = XElement.Parse(e.Result);


    }
```

as you can see we use DownloadStringCompletedHandler that occurs when an asynchronous resource-download operation completes.

Finally to parse the XML you can use XElement class [more informartion here](http://www.dotnetperls.com/xelement)